# Unexpected End of File in a Bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash, unix

This is just a little script to add a user to an e-mail MySQL database, assign an alias to him if an argument is defined, send a welcome email to the user and send e-mails to everybody else notifying about the newcomer. But everytime I try to run the script, I only get the message `UNEXPECTED END OF FILE`. Here's the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

USER=$1
SECTOR=$2

if [ -z "${SECTOR}" ];
then
   mysql --host=localhost --user=verysecretdatabaseuser --password=verysecretdatabasepass mydatabase << EOF
   insert into users (email,name,uid,gid,homedir,maildir,crypt,force_change_pwd) values("${USER}@example.com.br","${USER}",1001,1001, "/var/mail/${USER}/","/var/mail/${USER}/.maildir/",ENCRYPT("verysecretdefaultpass"), "yes" );
   EOF
else
   mysql --host=localhost --user=verysecretdatabaseuser --password=verysecretdatabasepass mydatabase << EOF
   insert into users(email,name,uid,gid,homedir,maildir,crypt,force_change_pwd)  values("${USER}@example.com.br","${USER}",1001,1001,"/var/mail/${USER}/","/var/mail/${USER}/.maildir/",ENCRYPT("verysecretdefaultpass"), "yes" ); EOF
   insert into alias(alias,destination) values ("${SECTOR}@example.com.br", "${USER}@example.com.br");
   EOF
fi

# send e-mail so my postfix can create the mail directories 
/usr/sbin/sendmail -f me@example.com.br "${USER}@example.com.br" << EOF
Subject: Bem Vindo!
Seja bem vindo ao Servidor de e-mails da Empresa! Com muito orgulho hospedamos nosso e-mail        em nosso próprio servidor. Em caso de dúvidas contacte <me@example.com.br>
.
EOF

# fetching everyone already in the database
users=`mysql --user=myverysecretuser --password=myverysecretpass -s -N -e "SELECT myverysecretfield FROM    myverysecretdatabase.myverysecretusertable"`

#sending an e-mail to each user
for user in $users
do
   echo "${user}"
   /usr/sbin/sendmail -f me@example.com.br "${user}" << EOF
   Subject: Funcionario novo!
   Prezados, deem as boas vindas ao funcionario novo "${USER}" que acabou de entrar no  departamento de "${SECTOR}". Para se comunicar com o funcionario novo, basta enviar e-mails   para: "${USER}@example.com.br". O funcionario novo tambem recebera e-mails que forem   enviados para "${SECTOR}@example.com.br".
   .
   EOF
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When asking help, indentation is more than just an option. Help you & us.

Comment: Well, since it has a few lines I didn't realize it could be dificult to read.

Comment: It's not difficult to indent, so what ?

Comment: Hmmm... didn't know you can manually specify end of file by inserting the word `EOF`

Comment: EOF does not signify end of file in the strictest sense here; `<< FOO ... FOO` would work just as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
#! /bin/bash

USER=$1
SECTOR=$2

if [ -z "${SECTOR}" ];
then
   mysql --host=localhost --user=verysecretdatabaseuser --password=verysecretdatabasepass mydatabase << EOF
   insert into users (email,name,uid,gid,homedir,maildir,crypt,force_change_pwd) values("${USER}@example.com.br","${USER}",1001,1001, "/var/mail/${USER}/","/var/mail/${USER}/.maildir/",ENCRYPT("verysecretdefaultpass"), "yes" );
EOF
else
   mysql --host=localhost --user=verysecretdatabaseuser --password=verysecretdatabasepass mydatabase << EOF
   insert into users(email,name,uid,gid,homedir,maildir,crypt,force_change_pwd)  values("${USER}@example.com.br","${USER}",1001,1001,"/var/mail/${USER}/","/var/mail/${USER}/.maildir/",ENCRYPT("verysecretdefaultpass"), "yes" ); EOF
   insert into alias(alias,destination) values ("${SECTOR}@example.com.br", "${USER}@example.com.br");
EOF
fi

# send e-mail so my postfix can create the mail directories 
/usr/sbin/sendmail -f me@example.com.br "${USER}@example.com.br" << EOF
Subject: Bem Vindo!
Seja bem vindo ao Servidor de e-mails da Empresa! Com muito orgulho hospedamos nosso e-mail        em nosso próprio servidor. Em caso de dúvidas contacte <me@example.com.br>
.
EOF

# fetching everyone already in the database
users=`mysql --user=myverysecretuser --password=myverysecretpass -s -N -e "SELECT myverysecretfield FROM    myverysecretdatabase.myverysecretusertable"`

#sending an e-mail to each user
for user in $users
do
   echo "${user}"
   /usr/sbin/sendmail -f me@example.com.br "${user}" << EOF
   Subject: Funcionario novo!
   Prezados, deem as boas vindas ao funcionario novo "${USER}" que acabou de entrar no  departamento de "${SECTOR}". Para se comunicar com o funcionario novo, basta enviar e-mails   para: "${USER}@example.com.br". O funcionario novo tambem recebera e-mails que forem   enviados para "${SECTOR}@example.com.br".
   .
EOF
done
```

The closing `EOF` must be at the beginning of the line.

You can test your script in `dry-run` mode with :

```
bash -n script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what did change?

Comment: It's aliiive!! Thank you very much!